# How to delete "invisible" white areas on .png image with Corel Paintshop?

Tags: transparency, png, background, photo-editing

Could someone help me? I had a problem with .png images. Well, I cut  an image and saved as .png with transparent background and this what I see with different photo viewers :

1. Corel Instant viewer

[image]

2. Fast Stone

[image]

Why I see white areas with Corel Instant viewer while I can't see them with Fast Stone and in Corel Paintshop? Also I can't remove them with eraser tool as well!! I'll be so glad to receive a helping tips from  graphic designers! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

The Corel viewer is only showing pixels that are 100% transparent as transparent. Anything that is partially transparent (less than 100% opacity, but not completely transparent) will show up in the viewer -- but *only* in that viewer (or another viewer that does not do/understand alpha transparency). If you remove those partially transparent pixels, you will no longer have a smooth-looking outline.